# geoserver configuration 'Could not initialize class org.geotools.image.ImageWorker'

Tags: geoserver

I installed geoserver 2.2.4 on windows 7. I then tried to open geoserver demo service with quantum gis desktop 1.8.0.

First I tried the wfs service with ghttp://localhos..:8080/geoserver/wfs?version=1.0.0 url and it worked perfectly.

Second I tried the same service (tobb:states, tasmania:roads) with ghttp://localho..:8080/geoserver/wms and the service catalog loaded. When I choose one of them I recieve this error.

I think I have to add some configuration for wms but I'm not sure.

```
Could not initialize class org.geotools.image.ImageWorker
```

---

Is it enough?

```
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
2013-02-13 10:54:34,220 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: No service: ( ows )
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:518)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:23)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
2013-02-13 11:27:19,877 WARN [config.CustomEditorConfigurer] - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [org.geotools.util.Version; offending editor instance: org.geoserver.platform.util.VersionPropertyEditor@18eb4a8
2013-02-13 11:27:20,047 ERROR [geoserver.global] - 
----------------------------------
- GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.2.4\data_dir
----------------------------------
2013-02-13 11:27:20,113 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,114 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,115 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,116 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'dem'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,116 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'giant_polygon'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,117 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'grass'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,118 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,118 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,119 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,119 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,120 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,121 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poly_landmarks'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,121 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,122 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,122 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,123 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,124 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,124 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,125 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_streams'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,126 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'tiger_roads'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,127 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace cite
2013-02-13 11:27:20,130 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,132 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,133 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,134 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,136 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,137 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,138 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
2013-02-13 11:27:20,561 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'ch11', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:20,564 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'ch11'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,248 WARN [referencing.factory] - Axis elements found in a wkt definition, the force longitude first axis order hint might not be respected:
PROJCS["WGS84 / Simple Mercator", GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295]], PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP_Google"], PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], UNIT["m", 1.0], AXIS["x", EAST], AXIS["y", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","54004"]]
2013-02-13 11:27:21,302 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'DNM_DURAK', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,307 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'ch11'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,317 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'DNM_DURAK'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,486 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'zonsinir', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,487 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'ch11'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,488 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'zonsinir'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,495 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'arcGridSample', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,497 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,517 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,523 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'arcGridSample'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,885 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Arc_Sample'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,895 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'img_sample2', disabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,895 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,909 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095', disabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,910 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'img_sample2'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,911 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Pk50095'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,916 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'mosaic', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,916 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,919 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:21,920 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic'
2013-02-13 11:27:21,949 WARN [imagemosaic.catalog] - BBOXFilterExtractor::extractBasicProperties(): passed typename is null, using: mosaic
2013-02-13 11:27:22,101 WARN [imagemosaic.Utils] - Unable to find sample image for path C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.2.4\data_dir\coverages\mosaic_sample\sample_image
2013-02-13 11:27:22,102 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.2.4/data_dir/coverages/mosaic_sample/mosaic.shp
2013-02-13 11:27:22,103 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,182 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'worldImageSample', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,182 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,185 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,186 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'worldImageSample'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,196 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Img_Sample'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,201 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'sf', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,202 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,230 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,230 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,232 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'archsites'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,234 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'bugsites', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,235 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,236 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,238 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,238 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,239 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'restricted'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,241 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'roads', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,242 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,242 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,245 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,245 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'sf'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,246 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'streams'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,250 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'sfdem', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,250 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'sfdem'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,254 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,254 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,358 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,363 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'nyc', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,363 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,377 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,378 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,379 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'giant_polygon'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,380 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poi', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,381 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,381 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,383 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,383 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,384 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poly_landmarks'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,386 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,387 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'nyc'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,389 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,394 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'states_shapefile', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,395 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'states_shapefile'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,401 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,401 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states_shapefile'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,403 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,412 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'taz_shapes', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,412 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'taz_shapes'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,430 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,431 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,432 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,433 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_roads', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,434 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,434 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,436 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,436 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,437 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_state_boundaries'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,438 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
2013-02-13 11:27:22,439 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'taz_shapes'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,440 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_water_bodies'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,443 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,444 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,445 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tiger-ny'
2013-02-13 11:27:22,479 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************************************
2013-02-13 11:27:22,479 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.2.4\data_dir, using it as the default prefix. ***
2013-02-13 11:27:22,480 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - **************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: ghttp or http ?

Comment: You should share the full stack trace from the GeoServer own logs.

Comment: I had saw your answer, i want to ask if the system is 64 bit, is the jre must be 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

i solve my problem, i use jre 64 bit instead of jre 32 bit